# getopts is not parsing my command line options

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm running bash version 4.2, and I'm trying to parse command line parameters with builtin command `getopts`,

But getopts doesn't seem to parse it correctly, if `-s` wasn't the first parameter, it won't be parsed

`-s` not parsed:

```
%> ./getopt.sh aaa -s aaa
aaa
```

This one get's parsed

```
%> ./getopt.sh -s aaa
s: aaa
aaa
```

The script is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "bs:" opt
do
    case $opt in
        s)
            echo "s: $OPTARG"
            ;;
        *)
            echo not supported
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo $1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the (older) `getopt`, `getopts` does not rearrange the arguments to put the options
first. Therefore, in

```
./getopt.sh arg1 -s opt1
```

option-parsing stops as soon as the non-option `arg1` is seen.

Comment: * Or as soon as `--` is encountered.